# OOP design problem: responsibility in containee or container?

Tags: c#, c++, oop, class-design

I focus a lot on making my software design flexible and reliable, and one of the key concepts to achieve this is encapsulation.
Lately I have faced a special design problem and I can't argue (with myself) what is the best solution.

A concrete example illustrating the problem: A device has an address (on a bus). The device has multiple registers. A register also has an address (inside the device - aka. virtual address/mapped address), so for example to write to a register on the device, you have to write (registerAddress, value) to the address of the device.
I can't decide where to put the functionality of reading/writing registers:

1) a register should be able to read write itself, meaning it needs to know about the communication channel between the device and itself. This seems strange/wrong somehow, I can't explain why though..

2) The device reads/writes to/from registers. A register is just a placeholder for information (data, access rights etc) that the device can query/alter. This also seems wrong because the responsibility of reading/writing a register should really be in the register (like a file knows how to read/write itself).

What solution makes most sense and why? Maybe there is a completely different solution that makes more sense?

**Solution 1**

```
class Device
{
    private CommChan chan;
    private Register register1;
    private Register register2;
    ...

    public Device(int deviceAddress)
    {
        chan = new CommChan(deviceAddress);
        register1 = new Register(0x01, chan);
        ...
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        register1.Write(0x22);
        byte b = register1.Read();
    }
}

class Register
{
    private int address;

    ...

    public Read()
    {
        chan.InitTransfer(address)
        ... // Other setup
        return chan.Read(address);
    }

    public Write()
    {
        chan.InitTransfer(address)
        ... // Other setup
        chan.Write(value);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
class Device
{
    private CommChan chan;

    public Device(int address)
    {
        chan = new CommChan(address);
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        WriteRegister(0x01, 0x22);
        byte b = ReadRegister(0x01);
    }

    private byte ReadRegister(int address)
    {
        chan.InitTransfer(address)
        ... // Other setup
        return chan.Read(address);
    }

    private void WriteRegister(int address, int value)
    {
        chan.InitTransfer(address)
        ... // Other setup
        chan.Write(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? It seems pretty clearly to be C# code, and a C++ solution would likely look different than a C# solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Driven to the logical extreme, a bus is an object by itself.  Reading or writing a register is a bus operation, different busses have different ways to access a register.  Create a bus interface with methods ReadRegister and WriteRegister.

Overdoing this is certainly a consideration, I imagine the odds that you'll ever run this code on another type of bus are small.

Answer (score 1):

The question is really about "should Register be a separate entity?". Well it's up to you. You need to answer question: why it's necessary a Register to be a class?

Comment: The reason that register should be a class was that it collects the information regarding registers in a central place. A register might also have properties like read/write/readonly, accesstime, and so on. If register is a class it is easy to see why this is a good idea (concerning only this). However if one takes into account that register then needs to know about the communication channel, it starts to get ugly I think. I'm looking for some good explanations as to why one solution is better than the other or just some thoughts on them seperately.

Comment: Well, if CommChan is absolutely necessary to initiate transfer, there is no way to Register be on it's own?